# Suggestions on how to render a K map?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

I would like to render a K map to supplement my answers to questions, but I'm not quite skilled enough with mathjax to figure out how to do it, and I can't find any online resources to generate one. Does anyone have any suggestions? Can someone supply me with a mathjax template, and/or an online resource to generate one?

Comment: I improvised a MathJax Karnaugh map once, but it is a lot of work and a didn't solve drawing the groups: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/67657/8627

Comment: Here is an example I did with LibreOffice  Calc and the Gimp ... lot of work too: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/73837/8627

Comment: It will probably be a lot simpler to write it (neatly!) on paper and then scan it. If you use appropriate image resolution, size, and trimming, not just what happened to come out of the scanner, then it should be OK. Remember, the main points are clarity and enough attention to detail to not show disrespect.